# The grad function in both the {pracma} and the {numDeriv} libraries of R gives erroneous results

Tags: r, gradient-descent

I am interested in the 1st order numerical derivative of a self-defined function `pTgh_y(q,g,h)` with respect to q. For a special case, pTgh_y(q,0,0) = pnorm(q). In other words `pTgh_y(q,g,h)` is reduced to the CDF of the standard normal when g=h=0 (see picture below).

[image]

This means that d pTgh_y(0,0,0)/dq should equal to the following

```
dnorm(0)
```

> 0.3989423

```
grad(pnorm,0)
```

> 0.3989423

Here are some of my attempts with the grad function in the {pracma} library.

```
library(pracma)
# load pTgh and all relevant functions
grad(function(x){pTgh_y(x,0,0)},0)
```

> 0

```
grad(function(x){pTgh_y(x,0,0)},0,heps=1e-10)
```

> 0

Here are some of my attempts with the grad function in the {numDeriv} library.

```
library(numDeriv)
# load pTgh and all relevant functions
grad(function(x){pTgh_y(x,0,0)},0,method='simple')
```

> 0.3274016

```
grad(function(x){pTgh_y(x,0,0)},0,method='Richardson')
```

> -0.02505431

```
grad(function(x){pTgh_y(x,0,0)},0,method='complex')
```

> Error in pmin(x, .Machine$double.xmax) : invalid input type
>   Error in grad.default(function(x) { : 
>     function does not accept complex argument as required by method 'complex'.

None of these functions is giving correct result.

My `pTgh_y(q,g,h)` function is defined as follows

```
qTgh_y = function(p,g,h){                             
  zp = qnorm(p)
  if(g==0) q = zp                                    
  else     q = (exp(g*zp)-1)*exp(0.5*h*zp^2)/g       
  q[p==0] = -Inf
  q[p==1] = Inf
  return(q)
}

pTgh_y = function(q,g,h){                      
  if (q==-Inf) return(0)
  else if (q==Inf) return(1)
  else { 
    p = uniroot(function(t){qTgh_y(t,g,h)-q},interval=c(0,1))
    return(p$root)
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is flat around 0, thus computing a derivative of 0 is correct:

```
f = function(x){pTgh_y(x,0,0)}
h = 0.00001; f(0+h); f(0-h)
# [1] 0.5
# [1] 0.5

library(pracma)
grad(f, 0, heps=1e-02); grad(f, 0, heps=1e-03);
grad(f, 0, heps=1e-04); grad(f, 0, heps=1e-05)
# [1] 0.3989059
# [1] 0.399012
# [1] 0.4688766
# [1] 0
```

You need to increase the accuracy of your function `pTgh_y`:

```
pTgh_y = function(q,g,h){                      
    if (q==-Inf) return(0)
    else if (q==Inf) return(1)
    else { 
        p = uniroot(function(t){qTgh_y(t,g,h)-q},interval=c(0,1),
                    tol = .Machine$double.eps)
        return(p$root)
    } 
}
```

And now you get the result you wanted to have:

```
f = function(x){pTgh_y(x,0,0)}
grad(f, 0)
[1] 0.3989423
```